# Reproject EPSG:4326 to entire hemisphere polar stereographic. No EPSG code available?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, epsg

I am trying to gdal reproject a series of WSG84 (Lat/Lon `EPSG:4326`) `GeoTiff` into North Pole stereographic projection, covering the entire northern hemisphere from the equator up to the pole at 90 degree latitude.
I don't seem to be able to find the correct target srs EPSG code for this. Common North Pole stereographic projections (like `EPSG:3413` and `EPSG:3995`) state a validity domain north of 60 degree latitude.

I managed to get the correct result using `EPSG:3995` and first cropping the EPSG:4326 data between 0 and +90 latitude. But then the `gdalinfo` of the result still displays the > 60 north definition and I am afraid that this will lead to problems when further processing the file with GIS tools.

Closest thing I found was an ESRI code 102018, but this is not recognized by my `GDAL` and `GeoServer` software.

Is there an EPSG CRS code for the entire northern hemisphere in stereographic projection?

Comment: You may be able to supply a WKT as a custom CRS for GeoServer ~ https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/crshandling/customcrs.html

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like an interesting option. Much appreciated.